# How do i use spread syntax to copy the values of only specific keys from json object (returned from API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

In React Redux, Reducers state change needs to copy values of only specific keys. How do i do that using spread syntax.

```
const initialState = {
    Information: {
      Manufacturer: undefined,
      Model: undefined
}
};
```

My structure is as above. I get a response from REST as below:

```
{
"@odata.context": "/redfish/v1/$metadata#ComputerSystem.ComputerSystem",
"@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Systems/1/",
"Bios":{
"@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/systems/1/bios/"
"Manufacturer": "ABC"
}
```

How do i extract value of only Manufacturer.

Comment: Could you please **edit your question** to include the parts of your code that produce the problem? It's very hard to answer your question if we don't see the code that isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a code example, I could give a better answer, but here's a shot:

```
function getSpecificKeys (input) {
    const { foo, bar, baz, ...other } = input
    return { foo, bar, baz } // to return only foo, bar baz
    // or, return every other key/value
    // return other
}
```

## Update

This is what I understood from your comment.

```
// You have a data structure like this:
const info = { a: undefined, b: undefined }

// You want to write a function that updates info with payload
// where payload looks like this
const payload = { 
    model: { a: "a value" },
    date: { b: "b value" }
}

// therefore the function should look like this
function mergePayload (info, payload) {
    const { model: { a }, date: { b } } = payload
    return { ...info, a, b }
    // NOTE that this will return a new object and not modify info reference
    // if you want to MODIFY info, then do this:
    // info.a = a
    // info.b = b
}
```

Comment: Consider a code snippet below:
//structure:
info{
a:undefined,
b:undefined};
//function to update the structure:
(...info, ...payload)
payload would be :
payload:
    model:
        a:"a is here"
    date:
        b:"date is here"